# Proper XML application for storing old text documents (talmud, bible, etc.)

Tags: html, xml, xhtml, sgml

I am planning to set up a simple, but extensive database of old religious texts. I was wondering if anyone could suggest an existing XML compliant format for storing such documents. Preferably a simple one, easily transformed to xhtml. I've heard about TEI, but afaik, TEI is based on SGML and is not XML compliant. Thanks in advance, any input is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can try TEI Boilerplate. Description from the website:

> TEI Boilerplate is a lightweight solution for publishing styled TEI P5
>   content directly in modern browsers. With TEI Boilerplate, TEI XML
>   files can be served directly to the web without server-side processing
>   or translation to HTML

Also, I think there is a confusion: TEI is, actually, an XML-based language. Anyway, the address is this:

http://sourceforge.net/p/teiboilerplate/wiki/Home/

Hope it helps.